# Radio Button Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, radio-button

How do I bring my radio buttons closer to the labels?

```
input[type="radio"]{
   float: left;
   width: auto;
   margin-left: 3em;
}

<fieldset id="payment_method">
<legend>Payment Method</legend>
<input type="radio" name="payment_method"value="Bill Me">
<label for= "payment1"> Bill Me</label>
<input type="radio" name="payment_method"value="Bill Me">
<label for= "payment2">Credit Card</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to float your inputs, you can just give the labels a negative margin instead like so:

```
label {
margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't apply any rules to your radio input. As all form elements are non Block-level elements (excluding `form` itself) so you don't need to `float` them (in your case) and remove the extra `margin`. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar3g9/1/)

```
input[type="radio"] {
    /* No styling */
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw the fiddle, but I am not understanding. If I have no styling in the input[type="radio"] than they become vertical aligned again.

Answer (score 0):

I like wrapping my input/label pairs in a `<div>` for easier styling. After that you could just remove the line break between the label and input tags:

```
<fieldset id="payment_method">
  <legend>Payment Method</legend>
  <div class="fieldgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method"value="Bill Me"><label for= "payment1">Bill Me</label>
  </div><!--/.fieldgroup-->
  <div class="fieldgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method"value="Bill Me"><label for= "payment2">Credit Card</label>
  </div><!--/.fieldgroup-->
</fieldset>
```

It's not terribly pretty, but it is the most cross-browser compatible solution, since each browser treats inline-block spacing differently.

Or, if you want to keep your code tidy, you can use floats like you tried originally:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/kgrote/pen/csGif)

```
input[type='radio'],
label {
  float: left;
}
.fieldgroup:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```